# Getting "Object Reference Error" while adding String.Format in StringBuilder

Tags: c#-2.0, stringbuilder, string.format

I am getting "object reference error" while putting string.format in stringbuilder. I have below code in C#2.0

```
public const string PageLinkGoogleMarkup = "<link rel=\"alternate\" hreflang=\"{0}\" href=\"{1}www.mysite.com{2}{3}\" />\r\n";
```

Now when I am adding this to HtmlTextWriter it is working fine, as below:

```
HtmlTextWriter writer (Object);
writer.write(string.format(PageLinkGoogleMarkup,str[1],header,links,querystr)); //This works perfect
```

And when I tries to add this above code to StringBuilder instead of HtmlTextWriter it gives error:

As there is big loop so I decided to go with appending everything to StringBuilder first and at last rendering using writer.Write (Whole html in a bunch), please below code

```
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
sb.Append(string.format(PageLinkGoogleMarkup,str[1],header,links,querystr)); //here i get object reference error

writer.Write(sb.ToString());
```

Please suggest!!

Thanks.

Comment: Do you mean "Object reference not set to an instance of an object"?

Comment: Yes, "Object reference not set to an instance of an object"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One of the following variables is null when you are using it in the StringBuilder code (but was not null when you used it in the working code):

```
str (or the item in index [1])
header
links
querystr
```

Use the debugger to figure out which one is null, fix that, and the code should work fine.

Comment: I don't think that is the issue as it works perfect with writer.write..any ideas

Comment: You have not provided enough code to be entirely sure which one is null, but I'm fairly sure that this is the problem.

Comment: see onething "querystr" can be empty but not null as it if current page has querystring then only this variable will have value , does that can cause issue

Comment: Problem Resolved actually StringBuilder object was getting in NULL